# Extending A ListBox with an ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to extend a ListBox with a custom ItemTemplate but when I run my code the ItemTemplate does not get applied?

```
    <ListBox x:Class="ExtendedCheckedListbox"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExtListBoxPOC"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Description}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>


private YesNoModel YesNo = new YesNoModel();

{
    DataContext = YesNo;
    cbl.ItemsSource = YesNo;

}
```

My main Window XAML which uses the control called cbl which has the ItemsSource set in code behind:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExtListBoxPOC"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:ExtendedCheckedListbox x:Name="cbl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Model class is this:

```
public class YesNoModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And I am adding items here:

```
{
    YesNo.Add(new YesNoModel() { Description = "Yes", Value = 1 });
    YesNo.Add(new YesNoModel() { Description = "No", Value = 2 });
    YesNo.Add(new YesNoModel() { Description = "N/A", Value = 3 });
}
```

Code behind the ExtendedCheckedListbox View:

```
public class ExtendedCheckedListbox : ListBox
{
}
```

Comment: Are you setting Itemsource for the ListBox from code or not setting it at all?

Comment: Yes from the code but I just get a list of (Collection)

Comment: is Description a dependency Property ?

Comment: Provide C# code aswell please

Comment: can you edit and add your code part to the question

Comment: Yes, the data all binds fine but shows a list of "(Collection") which is from the class I am binding to. It ignores the ItemTemplate format totally.

Comment: You need to add the control code, and also the calling xaml implementation

Comment: YesNo model returns 3 items

Comment: You do not set the ItemsSource anywhere.

Comment: ItemsSource and DataContext is set in code behind

Comment: For what reason do you create a derived ListBox at all? Just use a ListBox with an appropriate ItemTemplate in the MainWindow's XAML. Besides that, when you assign a YesNoModel instance to the ItemsSource property, it must implement the IEnumerable interface. Show us the YesNoModel implementation.

Comment: I need to create it as I need to add it dynamically in code behind many times

Comment: It works in a normal Window but now I need an extended control to reuse and add more dependency properties

Comment: Show us the YesNoModel implementation. And also the ExtendedCheckedListbox code behind, at least its constructor. If you derive from controls that aren't UserControls you would usually have a default Style instead of direct XAML. See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Comment: YesNoModel seems to be the item class you want to show in your ListBox. What do you expect to see when you assign a single YesNoModel instance to the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl? There should of course be a collection of YesNoModels. Or is `private YesNoModel YesNo = new YesNoModel();` just nonsense code?

Comment: YesNo is a list of YesNoModel and binds fine and show 3 items as expected but just shows all 3 as the model class and ignores the itemtemplate

Comment: So what is `private YesNoModel YesNo = new YesNoModel();` in your question? Anyway, see my answer for what went wrong with your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derived ListBox simply ignores the XAML, because you did apparently not call `InitializeComponent()` anywhere.

However, the usual way to derive from a control is to create a default Style in `Themes\Generic.xaml`. Add a "custom control" to your Visual Studio project and modify it like this:

```
public class ExtendedCheckedListBox : ListBox
{
    static ExtendedCheckedListBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(ExtendedCheckedListBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExtendedCheckedListBox)));
    }
}
```

Then change the content of the generated `Themes\Generic.xaml` file to this:

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExtendedCheckedListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Description}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help